# Can I use Mini DisplayPort -> VGA adapter to connect a Thunderbolt 2 port to a VGA display?

Tags: thunderbolt, mini-displayport

I've a MacBook early 2015 that has Thunderbolt 2 ports. I have an old VGA monitor that I would like to use. I'm currently using HDMI port to connect my first monitor (VGA will be second).

Answer (score 0):

You may find several such adapters on Amazon, so this is entirely possible.

As a random example (not a recommendation and without any guarantee), see
[Mini DisplayPort to VGA Cable (Thunderbolt 2 Compatible) with MacBook Air/Pro, Surface Pro/Dock, Monitor, Projector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FX50YT8).